# Webpack - Hot reloading works on dev server but not backend server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

Trying to get live reloading to work. Basically using the gearon-transform-boilerplate: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate

When I go to the dev server localhost:3000, i get live reloading

When I go to my backend server, and load the src data from the dev server ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/static/bundle.js"></script>
```

The reactjs page loads properly, but I get no hot reloading.(Which means when I change the components, I have to refresh the page to see the change)

How is this supposed to work? How do I get the backend server to essentially refresh the page when the src changes?

tags webpack webpack-hmr webpack-dev-server

Comment: Why would you want to load the `src` thru the server? Do you have any purpose of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the live reloading works while the `devServer.js` server it's running and you are in the port in which it's working because it creates some kind of endpoints only available for that port, basically without the dev-server or running out of the port it's not going to work.